# Spork with Capybara on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, bdd, capybara, spork

Here is my problem:
 I have started spork on my **Windows 7** and it just works fine (2 magazine_slave_service are setup -- after several attempts though). But when I run `bundle exec rspec spec` to execute my RSpec tests on another console, it gives me this error message:

```
undefined method 'read_all' for nil:NilClass <NoMethodError>
```

It's `in 1.8/gems/...../lib/spork/run_strategy/magazine.rb:89:in 'run'`

P.S: When I run `rake spec` it just does what's expected, my problem shows up when I want to use spork to speed up my BDD.

I'm running spork on **Win7-x86/Ruby1.8.7**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is:

1. Add `gem 'spork', '> 0.9.0.rc9'` (Instead of `gem 'spork', '~> 0.9.0.rc9'`)
2. Run "`rspec spec/models`" (for models)

Although, in general `spork` seems like doesn't work fine in windows ..sometimes it can't fork the processes properly. It works fine randomly (at least for me!)..You should try again and again to get it working.